# How can I calculate $z_1$ when the ball is on $y_1$?

Tags: vectors

I'm developing the Pong game and I want to know where the ball will be on axis Z when it is at $y_1$.

If the ball is at location $(y_0, z_0)$ (it doesn't move on axis X) I want to know the value of $z_1$ when the ball will be at location $(y_1, z_1)$. To know that, I know the value of $y_1$ and a its velocity on axes $Y$ and $Z$.

How can I compute the value of $z_1$?

To clarify, I don't have to take into account air friction.

With velocity I'm talking about a programming variable, named FVector, with three value $(a, b, c)$. These variable could be translate it into $ax + yb + cz$. This velocity is used to know where will be the ball.

Sorry, but I don't have a lot of math knowledge.

**Another to explain what I want to achieve is**:

I'm developing a game and I don't know how to compute this:

There is a ball moving on axes $Y$ and $Z$. There is also a paddle on $y_1$ which can only move along axis $Z$.

I don't know how to explain this clearly. The ball moves using a *Velocity* vector. In this programming language is something like `FVector (0.0f, 20.0f, 15.0f)`. It is something like, $0x + 20y + 15z$.

If the ball is at location $(y_0, z_0)$, how can I calculate $z_1$ when the ball is on $y_1$?

There is no gravity.

There is no air friction.

Comment: Do you want to consider air friction?

Comment: When you say "I know its velocity", does it mean you have the velocity as a function of time or its numerical value at some point? You cannot do much with just numerical values.

Comment: @IamWill I assume, that the velocity is the initial one.

Comment: @IamWill I have updated my question. I hope I have explained better. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Are you interested in only the result or also the way to establish it?

Comment: @Axel I'm interested in the formula to get the value of $z_1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By applying the second law of Newton with $g \approx 10 \, \mathrm{m.s}^{-1}$, one may show that (see the proof down below):

$$z_1-z_0 = \frac{-g}{2v_0^2 \cos^2 \alpha}(y_1-y_0)^2+\tan\alpha \cdot(y_1-y_0)$$

[image]
With $v_0 = \|\overrightarrow{v_0} \| = \sqrt{b^2+c^2} $ the initial speed at $(y_0,z_0)$ and,
$$\cos \alpha = \dfrac{b}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2}} = \dfrac{b}{v_0}$$

furthermore,

$$\tan \alpha = \dfrac{c}{b} $$

Therefore,

$$\boxed{z_1 = \dfrac{-g}{2b^2}(y_1-y_0)^2+\dfrac{c}{b}(y_1-y_0)+z_0}$$

Here's the proof:

The only force applied on your ball is assumed to be $\overrightarrow{F} = -m g \overrightarrow{e_z}$ with $m$ the mass of your ball and $\overrightarrow{e_z}$ a unitary vector in the direction of $z$. By applying Newton's second law of motion:

$$m \overrightarrow{a} = -m g \overrightarrow{e_z}$$

Therefore,

$$m\ddot{z} = -mg \quad \text{and} \quad \ddot{y} = 0$$

By integrating,

$$\dot{z}(t)-\dot{z}(0) = -gt \quad \text{and} \quad \dot{y}(t)=\dot{y}(0)$$

Hence,

$$ \dot{z}(t) = -gt+ \dot{z}(0) = -gt+c \quad \text{and} \quad \dot{y}(t)=b$$

Integrating one last time we get,

$$z(t) = -g\frac{t^2}{2} + ct+z_0 \quad \text{and} \quad y(t)=bt+y_0 $$

We can isolate $t$ as follows,

$$t = \frac{y-y_0}{b}$$

By reinjecting this into the equation along the $z$ axis:

$$z = \dfrac{-g}{2b^2}(y-y_0)^2+\dfrac{c}{b}(y-y_0)+z_0$$